# Специализация алиасом шаблонного параметра шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, gcc, language-lawyer, clang

```
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename> class>
struct A {
  A() { std::cout << '1'; }
};

template <typename>
struct X {};

template <typename T>
using Y = X<T>;

template <>
struct A<X> {
  A() { std::cout << '2'; }
};

int main() {
  A<X>{};
  A<Y>{};
}
```

Почему `gcc` последний выводит `22`, а `clang` - `21`? Как правильно и почему?

Comment: незачем спамить

Comment: @user7860670 здесь улучшено оформление + 3 дня никто не отвечает

Comment: можно поглотить этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1312225/455081

Answer (score 0):

`clang` прав, т.к. в соответствии со стандартом `A<X>` и `A<Y>` разные типы, `gcc` же считает их одинаковыми типами. Можно [добавить специализацию](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1Caxbk4TxJish9gmGgCC1zcEmCwJBo8HR4/Pr5jvbgQAnglGKxMJc9jsmAoFJd7qcvA49jcDgB2Ky3PaIiDzFEWPYTdAgFDLAi/Q5uPZgbiUw64kzIgAi9zpjNiaLut0%2BLyYbzJAKBzDYMNucIRAA0ccyaUyOU8uTyPoDgWw9gAVIU3LwpIx7ACa73pe1FZLVsSurOlD1l31JpthBGI8JJdyORtNEvRmOxdNx%2BMJaC8JLJZIpHDM1NZKMZt0l5ujMq%2B3J%2BQdtwvtjsRZJ1YO99wxNyxOLxBAJRIDNvJlNi4dpDKZtdj7JuwRJLCYwQLOY9zrcrquqJjbLzmZh/frbOZHEWtE4AFZeH4OFpSKhOG5rNY8ctVkmzLEeKQCJpJ4sANYgGcafScSTzo/Lzi8BQgS%2BHxeT0hwWAwRAgTCqSoBiQ5CUHUwAKMohhtEICCoAA7gu%2B5oM8dDcmkEEhLQ0FwQuS5IQkdADGBzAJAoMEEKQeEEcQADyAZYfBd5/pUNzEGBD6kExyA1PgC68PwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hvqQugtAYRgoOulj6HgERPpAiyoAkHRPhwAC0%2BKHPSpiWNYZgRI%2BW5rHo%2BLBOhUEwQx3C8PamDrPusHEEwCScDwU6zreUkrhw2D/sggHEHsqgABwAGy6TFkh7MAyDIHsEBpgwJ7YhAa4mUpey4IQJAHLuXDzM5R7zKe56XtOHA3qQLA1aQOG8EFj7PgelUft%2BEBIJx4XARAoHgZBmEOQhvCUa8aFjfRrUUagyH0DEEJGAA%2BhlJ6Lct0S0cIE2MaFLFsRwvCcdxwTsfxwiiOIIk3eJah3roZj6IYxiKTYtAqWpWLLlpaQ6fpxaGcZViWGZFkrFZ4zFrZc2HU5B5nG5vAeV5PnvnVc4tXeQUhQBRARdFcUJeCcnAGlW3ZblEM2AV%2BDEyVe7lV1b5VaQCDnFgMT/XVDVNReeOBexT4vpV1XC3VsQBUu7Xs1onN1WYcttexr5K4sABu0QpM4khAA%3D%3D) для `Y`, чтобы проверить это.

---

Чтобы `A<X>` и `A<Y>` были одинаковыми, должны быть одинаковыми `X` и `Y`.

[[temp.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.type#1):

> **Two *template-id*s are the same if**
>
> - their *template-name*s, *operator-function-id*s, or *literal-operator-id*s refer to the same template, and
> - their corresponding type *template-argument*s are the same type, and
> - their corresponding non-type *template-argument*s are template-argument-equivalent (see below) after conversion to the type
>   of the *template-parameter*, and
> - **their corresponding template *template-argument*s refer to the same template**.
>
> **Two *template-id*s that are the same refer to the same class**,
> function, or variable.

Однако в стандарте нет пункта, который говорит о том, что шаблонный алиас `Y` эквивалентен шаблонному классу `X`. Есть только [пункт](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.alias#2) про то, что некоторая специализация шаблонного алиаса эквивалентна соответствующему классу (т.е. `Y<int>` эквивалентно `X<int>`, но при этом `Y` не эквивалентно `X`).

---

Интересно, что одна из ранних версий C++11 стандарта содержала аналогичный пример, где было указано, что `A<X>` и `A<Y>` одинаковые типы. В связи с чем был опубликован [CWG-1244](https://wg21.link/cwg1244). В ответ на эту проблему в окончательный вариант C++11 попал [другой пример](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std11/temp.type#1) (вместо разрешения `A<X>` и `A<Y>` быть одним типом).

```
template<class T> struct X { };
template<class> struct Y { };
template<class T> using Z = Y<T>;
X<Y<int> > y;
X<Z<int> > z;
```

Это привело к публикации нового [CWG-1286](https://wg21.link/cwg1286), который предлагал таки добавить в стандарт пункты, разрешающие исходный пример. Однако пока этот *issue* не закрыт и находится в активном состоянии ([*drafting*](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#Issue%20Status)).